# how to get and send data using reactjs and redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have problem when trying to send data through the function action in redux,
my code is below

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {RetrieveCompany} from '../../folder/action/my.actions'

interface Icampaing{
   campaing: my_data
}

// campaing IS WORKING WELL, GET ME ALL MY DATA
const Personal: React.FC<Icampaing> = ({campaing}, props: nay) => {
    React.useEffect(()=>{
        let pf_id: any = campaing.profile ? campaing.profile.id : 0
        let pc_id: any = campaing.profile_ca

        // THE PROBLEM IS HERE SHOW ME THE ERROR
        // TypeError: props.RetrieveCompany is not a function
        props.RetrieveCompany(pf_id, pc_id)

    },[campaing])
     return(<>
         {campaing.all_data} // HERE WHEN LOAD DATA campaing WORKING WELL
     </>)

}
const mapStateToProps = (state: any) =>({
   campaing: state.campaing
})
const mapActionToProps = {
  RetrieveCompany
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionToProps)(Personal)
```

please help me, I think forget something.

best words, and happy new year.....!

Comment: Idk redux very well, but shouldn't it be `= ({campaing, RetrieveCompany}) =>` and then to use it you would do `RetrieveCompany(pf_id, pc_id)`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mapDispatchToProps` instead of `mapActionToProps`

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  RetrieveCompany: () => dispatch(RetrieveCompany())
  // Important: this could be just 
  // RetrieveCompany depends on how you define your action.
  // For naming, I would use camelCase
});
```

Because what you need to do here is to dispatch an action so that the store will update its state. Then you would read the data returned by `mapStateToProps`.

Comment: hello Viet, thanks for your answer, but there is an error, like this const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  RetrieveCompany: () => dispatch(RetrieveCompany()) // EXPECTED 2 ARGUMENTS, BUT GOT 0
});, please help me, I pass the 2 arg, like this dispatch(RetrieveCompany(pf_id, pc_id)), the error show me is "canot find name pf_id, pc_id, ca", please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think `RetrieveCompany` is not among props in deed. Try to spread the rest of the props if you do not want to explicitly name it:

```
interface Icampaing {
   campaing: my_data
   [propName: string]: any
}

const Personal: React.FC<Icampaing> = ({ campaing, ...props }) => {

...
```

or simply add it explicitly since you use it in the component anyways:

```
interface Icampaing {
   campaing: my_data
   RetrieveCompany: (pf_id: number, pc_id: number) => void
}

const Personal: React.FC<Icampaing> = ({ campaing, RetrieveCompany }) => {
```

Comment: hello gazdagergo, thanks for your answere,  there is an error the 2 answers in a infinity loop, and disable my data campaing, my function RetrieveCompany get a data using pf_id, pc_id, this two vars as number. please help me

Comment: OK, I've changed their types to number. Does that help?